# Derivative of optimal linear regression coefficient w.r.t. distribution shift

Tags: probability-theory, partial-derivative, expected-value, linear-regression

Assume I have the following model:
$$
x = f(u)\\
y = g(u)\\
u \sim \mathcal{N}(m, 1)
$$
I'm trying to derive the derivative of the optimal linear regression coefficient $w*$ for the model $y = wx + \epsilon$, i.e.
$$
\frac{\delta w^*}{\delta m}
$$
but I'm having some trouble framing the problem in probabilistic notation.

$$
w^* = \arg\max_w \mathbb{E}_{u \sim \mathcal{N}(m, 1)}\left[P(y|x)\right]\\
$$
where if we assume that the error term $\epsilon$ is normally distributed, this is equivalent to
$$
\begin{align}
w^* &= \arg\min_w \mathbb{E}_{u \sim \mathcal{N}(m, 1)}\left[(y - wx)^2\right]\\
&= \arg\min_w \mathbb{E}_{u \sim \mathcal{N}(m, 1)}\left[(g(u) - wf(x))^2\right]
\end{align}
$$

I am stuck here, as I do not know how to proceed to differentiate under an $\arg\min$ operation. I think I could handle the differentiation under $m$ in the expectation with something like the [log-derivative trick](https://andrewcharlesjones.github.io/journal/log-derivative.html) although I am not sure how to actually do that.

Does this make at least some sense? Feel free to post a complete solution if you have one, otherwise I welcome any suggestion.

Comment: You can get a formula for $w^*$ interms of the mean and covariance structures.